# Find users within a given radius

Tags: mysqli, geometry

I have a mySQL table with user name, latitude and longitude of the user. I would like to get a list of user who are inside the circle of a given latitude and longitude with given distance. For example my input Lat= 78.3232 and Long = 65.3234 and distance = 5 km. I would like to get the list of users who are inside 5km distance from the point 78.3232 and 65.3234. Is it possible to solve this with single query? Or can you give me a hint start solving this query? I am new to the geo based information.

Comment: you can try  [between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google gives me this :

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html

it gives you a good idea to start your work.. based on the distance between points (your circle radius)

imo, you need to define all points (surface) that are into this "circle", and check if your users are into this surface... in fact, a good way to do this would be to define ranges... for example :

lat : 72, long between 65 & 67
lat : 73, long between 64 & 69
... ...

if you do it with your precision xx.yyyy that will increase consequently the possibilities... it's just a mathematical challenge... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think a good place to start is with the Pythagorean theorem a^2 + b^2 = c^2 where a would = the difference in lat from point to Origin and b would = the difference in long.   and c would equal distance.

that solves the math point.

I would need some helping doing the conversion from distance in lat and distance in long.

is the going to be a local, state, or a world wide program? that will create changes as differences in longitude get small as you reach the poles and larger as your reach the equator.